# Is there a shortcut in PyCharm which highlights a code block

Tags: python, pycharm

In IntelliJ, if you double click after open flower bracket ({), it automatically highlights the entire reachable code block. Is there a similar shortcut present in PyCharm where I can highlight blocks of code post a colon is encountered (like for loops, function defs, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to do this, sort of. At least on mac.

Comment: Thank you, in MacOS it is actually option+double_tap up key

Comment: @UmeshSPadashetty well that depends on the context your cursor is in. If you put your cursor in a string, in brackets, in a loop etc it can take 10 taps of the up arrow to reach the block you want - if you put it just after the function definition you can get it in one. The whole point is that it is context aware. Glad this helped though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> for incremental selection. 
If you want to select the whole method, you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html